# How to repair a ceiling after removing glued on polystyrene covings?

Tags: ceiling

I had polystyrene covings in my apartment, and have removed them simply by ripping them off. Right now there's still glue left in many places on the ceiling, and in other places some of the plaster came off. See attached picture.

How can I restore the ceiling? It's a ceiling with quite a rough texture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will need to be done by scraping off the old glue with a paint scraper whether it be a straight blade

[image]

Or one with a curved blade

[image]

The straight blade, is typically pushed to scrape, the curved or hook type is pulled.

I prefer the hook type since in my opinion the control is better. The straight type can go in too far and gouge the drywall and make the repair more difficult.

In either case, use the scraper of choice to remove the glue left behind. The texture is a gypsum product, easily removed by scraping, so not much effort should be needed, and it won't be difficult to get to the paper facing of the drywall. There is no need to go that far, but as long as the paper is not torn through to the gypsum core, not a problem if the surface gets roughened by the action.

When repairing texture, I usually sand around the repair area to feather in the new material. This also helps in filling in the areas where the drywall was removed down t the paper. The smooth area around the damage will be easier to repair using joint compound.
[image]

Fill the places that are recessed so they are filled level with the surrounding area. Let dry, sand the next day so it is matching the surrounding area.

Prime the places that were repaired if you choose too. There are folk who think it is best to prime, others who think it does not matter. On the ceiling, to me it does not matter, durability will not be an issue.

Next step will take some getting used too. Also before all this is started, you should put down floor protection and mask off the walls and anything below the areas you need to repair. It will be a dusty mess. It will get all over you, since all of it is overhead.
You will need a can of spray texture to match your ceiling, which looks like a very heavy orange peel.

[image]

It needs practice, read the instructions on the can and it will tell you how to use it.

All pictures courtesy Home Depot

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer.